# How to add command retry to sensu checks?

Tags: puppet, sensu

I have the following sensu check defined in puppet

```
sensu::check { 'check_kubernetes_kubelet':
   interval    => 60,
   timeout     => 30,
   command     => 'check_http -H :::name::: -p 10248 -u /healthz -e "200 OK"',
   subscribers => ['kubernetes_minion'],
   contacts    => ['sensu_high'],
}
```

I want to add command retry to this check.
This check should start alerting to its contacts only after N consecutive command executions return error.

In this example, say N is 2. 
Say a failure happens right after check_X. Then 60 seconds later check_X+1 will return error. After another 60 seconds check_X+2 will also fail. I want the alerting to start after check_X+2's error.

---

I think sensu [filters](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/filters.html)  may be useful. 
It looks like I need to create a filter like [here](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/filters.html#example-handling-repeated-events). But then how do I associate that filter with this check? Do I need to define a custom handler too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Occurences is what you need to use.
`occurrences  => 2,`

Comment: Yes we end up using occurrences too. But we needed to put the occurrences field in the `custom` field. So it looked like 
`custom      => {
   'occurrences' => 3,
 },`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [handlers](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/handlers.html). When your check triggers and event, this gets to the handler or handlers you have defined for it (search for "handler" in [checks](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/checks.html)). Then, each handler can have one or more filters associated.

From the doc:

> When the Sensu server is processing an Event, it will check for the definition of a handler (or handlers). Prior to executing each Handler, the Sensu server will first apply any configured filter (or filters) for the Handler

Comment: Looking at the handler docs, what type of handler would you use? How would the filter for that look like? Looking at the enterprise edition, it looks like there is a handle_when [parameter](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.0/enterprise/filters/handle-when.html#examples) to sensu::check. However I do not see it in the open source sensu::check [definition](https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet/blob/master/manifests/check.pp#L93)

Comment: The handler type depends on what you want to do with the data generated by the event. The two most used are "pipe", if you want to send it to a command (built-in or created by you), or "tcp/udp" to send the info to a socket. I'm not familiar with the other types... Regarding the filter, I think you need to use "occurences" https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/reference/filters.html#example-handling-repeated-events